# How can we test a camera application without a paid iOS developer account?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to test my camera application on iPhone without paying for an iOS developer account. Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: It's not possible. Anything in the SDK that you need to test on a device means you have to purchase a subscription to the developer program. No exceptions.

Comment: Is it possible to test the iphone app on more than 1 iphone with a single certificate?

Comment: Yes, up to 100 different devices each year.

Comment: Is it possible to test the iPhone application as a standalone application on iPhone(Without using xcode)?

Comment: @NaveenChauhan as a registered developer you can make "ad-hoc" distributions of your application which will only work for devices included in the provisioning profile you compiled the application with (you are allowed up to 100). These distributions do note require xcode for installing, just itunes.

Comment: Yes but its a tedious solution. You will need to Jailbreak your iPhone first, and install openSSH. You'll then be able to access the phones directory (through an FTP program). You compile your app on xcode for device-release, and place it in the applications folder in the phone. You will need to self sign the application (as this is what you pay Apple for), you can do this a number of ways but install ldid from Cydia (jailbroken app store) then run the command in Terminal (another app) you'll then be able to run it. http://www.saurik.com/id/8 Very tedious and time consuming, pay the £60 :)

Answer (score 3):

Not possible, in order to use some of the hardware features such as the Camera you must deploy to a physical device. This requires a paid developer account.

Comment: not 100% accurate as you can deploy and self sign... but not recommended (as mentioned in my comment) :)

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it was possible through jailbreak but I have never tried it. If you are taking iOS development serious you need a paid developer account IMO.

Comment: absolutely. You'll spend more time getting the thing on the phone than developing. You're also unable to debug unless you fake the signature in Xcode which is really painful, and I'm sure Apple would have added extra checks in 4.x to stop it.